# Bootstrap 4 Complex Column Reordering Extra Whitespace

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, layout, responsive-design

Yesterday I was given a design that has some complex column reordering between a mobile one-column layout and a tablet/desktop two-column layout. Using Bootstrap 4, I have laid out the page using the standard "mobile-first" approach and then I'm using `order-md-*` classes to move columns into place for tablet/desktop. The problem is, some of the columns have extra whitespace before/after them on the two-column layout. I assume this is because of how the column counts are adding up with the reordered columns on tablet/desktop.

Here is a demo of the code. You can see that the single-column version looks good but the two-column has weird blocks of whitespace.

https://www.codeply.com/p/EbqtBPE7ZR

Thanks in advance.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container-lg">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-start">
        <div class="col-md-7 order-md-0">
            <h1>Title Here</h1>
            <p>Subtitle goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 order-md-1">
            <p> <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/700x350' class="img-fluid"> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 order-md-0">
            <h2>Post Author Here</h2>
            <p>2021-01-01 | Category1, Category 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 order-md-1">
            <h2>Post Excerpt</h2>
            <p>The post excerpt goes here and sometimes it can be so long that is pushes beyond the post's featured image.</p>
            <p>The post excerpt goes here and sometimes it can be so long that is pushes beyond the post's featured image.</p>
            <p>The post excerpt goes here and sometimes it can be so long that is pushes beyond the post's featured image.</p>
            <p>The post excerpt goes here and sometimes it can be so long that is pushes beyond the post's featured image.</p>
            <p>The post excerpt goes here and sometimes it can be so long that is pushes beyond the post's featured image.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 order-md-1">
            <p>This is the post content. This is the post content. This is the post content.This is the post content. This is the post content. </p>
            <p>This is the post content. This is the post content. This is the post content.This is the post content. This is the post content. </p>
            <p>This is the post content. This is the post content. This is the post content.This is the post content. This is the post content. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8 order-md-last">
            <h2>Post Author w/Bio</h2>
            <p><strong>Auhtor name here</strong><br /> The author's bio will be here. The author's bio will be here. The author's bio will be here. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 order-md-1">
            <h2>Post Tags:</h2>
            <p>Tag1, Tag2, Tag3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 order-md-1">
            <h2>Related Content</h2>
            <p>Related Post Title 1</p>
            <p>Related Post Title 2</p>
            <p>Related Post Title 3</p>
            <h2>Related Products</h2>
            <p>Related Product Name 1</p>
            <p>Related Product Name 2</p>
            <p>Related Product Name 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BS4 runs basicly a flex layout , it can draw columns or lines but not both at the same time, that's why there is white space. grid could  work or a column CSS layout: try add this to your codeply CSS last  : `@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .row {
        display: block;
        /* kills flex display */
        column-count: 2;
    }

    .row>* {
        min-width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
}` and tell us if that meets somehow what you look for ;)

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/p/EbqtBPE7ZR for the show

Comment: @G-Cyrillus - Your code gives me two columns without whitespace but it loses all of the Bootstrap custom ordering of the columns so unfortunately, I don't think it will work. Thanks for taking the time though.

Comment: okay, look at masonry layout to see other options filling up columns without blanks ;) remember, have fun coding ;)